# Correct way of initialising the variables using constructor

Tags: php, oop

Is this the correct way of initializing the variables using constructor?

```
class Customer
{
    public $custId;
    public $custName;
    function _construct()
    {
        $this->custId   = 'Eazy01';
        $this->custName = 'EazyLearnKaloor';
    }

    function DisplayDetails()
    {
        echo "$custId<br>";
        echo "$custName";
    }
}

$obj = new Customer();
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

Comment: If those values are really to be hard-coded, you may as well assign them in the class without having a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double undersores as in `__construct()`.

```
class Customer
{
    public $custId;
    public $custName;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->custId   = 'Eazy01';
        $this->custName = 'EazyLearnKaloor';
    }

    function DisplayDetails()
    {
        echo "$this->custId<br>"; // use $this here
        echo "$this->custName"; // use $this here
    }
}

$obj = new Customer();
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

Also you could pass variables to constructor:

```
    function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->custId   = $id;
        $this->custName = $name;
    }
```

Then when initialising new class you can do:

```
$var = new Customer('Eeazy01', 'EazyLearnKaloor');
```

Comment: That was probably just a typo.

Comment: Why the quotes around the variables in `DisplayDetails`?!

Comment: I just used the code that was originally in the question. While it's not usual syntax, it's still valid.

Answer (score 2):

imho correct way is

```
class Customer
{
    public $custId;
    public $custName;

    // double underscores
    function __construct($custId = 'Eazy01', $custName = 'EazyLearnKallor')
    {
        $this->custId   = $custId;
        $this->custName = $custName;
    }

    function DisplayDetails()
    {
        echo $this->custId . '<br />' . $this->custName;
    }
}

$obj = new Customer();
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a double underscore: `__construct` and when you want to print your variables you have to use `$this->propertyName`. The rest of your code is correct.

```
class Customer
{
    public $custId;
    public $custName;
    function _construct($custId = '', $custName = '')
    {
        $this->custId   = $custId;
        $this->custName = $custName;
    }

    function DisplayDetails()
    {
        $content  = $this->custId . "<br />";
        $content .= $this->custName;
        echo $content;
    }
}

$obj = new Customer();
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

If you use this way of coding you don't have to pass parameters to the constructor. You could use:

```
$obj = new Customer(); 
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

and

```
$obj = new Customer('Hello', 'World');
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

But also

```
$obj = new Customer(12);
$obj->DisplayDetails();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...but the constructor in PHP is named __construct()

Also, you should use Getters and Setters for your Attributes and make them protected or private

Answer (score 0):

Use double underscores in __construct() and `$this` to 'echoes' parameters on `DisplayDetails`

```
function DisplayDetails()
{
    echo $this->custId, "<br>", $this->custName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a "correct" way, but that will work just fine. Usually, you pass the values to the constructor (note double underscore):

```
function __construct($id, $name)
{
    $this->custId   = $id;
    $this->custName = $name;
}
```

Then:

```
$obj = new Customer('Eazy01', 'EazyLearnKaloor');
```

Also, when you refer to them, you need to prefix them with $this:

```
function DisplayDetails()
{
    echo $this->custId . "<br>";
    echo $this->custName;
}
```

Comment: Oops yep, just cut-and-pasted from the source, fixed.